# Assign Seller product issue

Tags: magento-1.9

I have Marketplace **Assign product** in my website. I have a problem

Let us assume I have product with **2 seller** if customer click add to cart in **A seller** so it's **A Seller Product added to cart** it's working fine. then customer click same product add to cart in another B seller it redirect to cart but A seller qty only increased not adding B Seller. How to add this seller product also separately in cart

**my observer**

```
<?php
Class Webkul_Mpassignproduct_Model_Observer
{
    /*after update carttttt*/   
    public function cartUpdate($observer) {
        $db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
        $cart = $observer->getCart()->getQuote()->getAllItems();
    //  $cart_data =  Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
    $cart_data = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAlltems(); 
        $info = $observer->getInfo();
        foreach($cart_data as $item) {
            $current_qty=$info[$item->getId()]['qty'];
            $productid= $item->getProductId();
            $mpassignproductId=0;
            foreach($item->getOptions() as $option) {
                $temp=unserialize($option['value']);
                if($temp['mpassignproduct_id'])
                    $mpassignproductId=$temp['mpassignproduct_id'];
            }
            if($mpassignproductId) {
                $productdetail=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($mpassignproductId);
                $price=$productdetail->getPrice();
                $avlqty=$productdetail->getQty();
                $seller=$productdetail->getSellerId();

                $diff=$avlqty-$current_qty;
                if($diff>0) {
                    $item->setCustomPrice($price);
                    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
                    $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
                } else if($diff<=0) {
                    if($current_qty > $avlqty) {
                        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
                        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
                        $item->setQty($avlqty);
                        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addNotice('Number of quantity not available.');
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $adminAvlQty=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getAssignProDetails($productid);
                if($current_qty >  $adminAvlQty['sellerqty']) {
                    $item->setQty($adminAvlQty['sellerqty']);
                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addNotice('Number of quantity not available.');
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /*after product added to cart*/ 
    public function productCart(Varien_Event_Observer $obs) {
    //  $cart_data =  Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
        $cart_data = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAlltems(); 
        $item = $obs->getQuoteItem();
        $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
        $db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
        $productid=$item->getProductId();           
        foreach ($cart_data as $cart) { 
            if($cart->getProductId()==$productid){
                $quantity=$cart->getQty();
            }
        }
        $productid= $item->getProductId();
        $mpassignproductId=0;
        foreach($item->getOptions() as $option) {
            $temp=unserialize($option['value']);
            if($temp['mpassignproduct_id'])
                $mpassignproductId=$temp['mpassignproduct_id'];

        }
        if($mpassignproductId) {
            $productdetail=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($mpassignproductId);
            $price=$productdetail->getPrice();
            $avlqty=$productdetail->getQty();
            $seller=$productdetail->getSellerId();

            $diff=$avlqty-$quantity;
            if($diff>0) {
                $item->setCustomPrice($price);
                $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
                $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
            } else if($diff<=0) {
                if($quantity > $avlqty) {
                    $item->setCustomPrice($price);
                    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
                    $item->setQty($avlqty);
                    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addNotice('Number of quantity not available.');
                }
            }
        } else {
            $adminAvlQty=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getAssignProDetails($productid);
            if($quantity >  $adminAvlQty['sellerqty']) {
                $item->setQty($adminAvlQty['sellerqty']);
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addNotice('Number of quantity not available.');
            }
        }
    }

    public function productUpdateCart(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) { 
        $item=$observer->getItem();
        $proprice=$item->getProduct()->getPrice();
        $item->setCustomPrice($proprice);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($proprice);
        $item->save();  
    }

    public function afterPlaceOrder1($observer) { 
        $lastOrderId=$observer->getOrder()->getId();
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($lastOrderId);
        $ordered_items = $order->getAllItems();
        foreach ($ordered_items as $item) {
            $options=$item->getProductOptions();
            $productId=$item->getProductId();
            $mpassignproductId=$options['info_buyRequest']['mpassignproduct_id'];
            if($mpassignproductId) {
                $collect=Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('mageproid',array('eq'=>$productId))
                    ->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',array('eq'=>$lastOrderId));
                foreach($collect as $val) {
                    $slqty=$val['magequantity'];
                    $saleslistId=$val['autoid'];
                }
                $mpassignModel=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($mpassignproductId);

                if($saleslistId) {
                    $saleslistModel=Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->load($saleslistId);
                    $saleslistModel->setMageproownerid($mpassignModel->getSellerId());
                    $saleslistModel->setMpassignproductId($mpassignproductId);
                    $saleslistModel->save();

                    $asqt=$mpassignModel->getQty();
                    $nasqt = $asqt-$slqty;
                    $mpassignModel->setQty($nasqt);
                    $mpassignModel->save();
                } 
            }
        }
    }
    /*Pending................................on product delete from seller*/
    public function deleteProductCheck($observer) {
        $productid=$observer->getId();
        $collection=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('product_id',array('eq'=>$productid))
                        ->addFieldToFilter('qty',array('gt'=>0));
        $collection->setOrder("price","ASC");
        if(count($collection)>0) {
            foreach($collection as $assignproduct) {
                $collectionpro=Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$productid));
                foreach($collectionpro as $row) {
                    $row->setUserid($assignproduct->getSellerId());
                    $row->save();
                    // set qty to product
                    $data=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getAssignProDetails($productid);

                    $_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productid);
                    $_product->setPrice($assignproduct->getPrice());
                    $_product->save();

                    $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productid);
                    $stockItem->setProductId($productid)->setStockId(1);
                    $savedStock = $stockItem->save();
                    $stockItem->load($savedStock->getId())->setQty($data['assignqty'])->save();
                    $stockItem->setData('is_in_stock', 1); 
                    $savedStock = $stockItem->save();
                }
                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setIsAssing($assignproduct->getMpassignproductId());
                $assignproduct->delete();
                break;
            }
        } else {
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setIsAssing(0);
        }
    }

    //when admin will the delete the product
    public function DeleteProduct($observer) { 
        $collection = Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getCollection()
                                ->addFieldToFilter('product_id ',$observer->getProduct()->getId());
        foreach($collection as $data){          
            Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->load($data['mpassignproduct_id'])->delete();         
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code I can't really find out where you set options on the item, so I assume this might be the problem.

By adding an option to the product and the item, you tell Magento that even if it is the same product in the cart, it should be handled as different items.

When I had to do this, I observed `checkout_cart_product_add_after` to add my options; add this to your config.xml file in the `<events>` section:

`<checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    <observers>
        <my_observer_name>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>mymodule/observer</class>
            <method>checkoutCartProductAddAfter</method>
        </my_observer_name>
    </observers>
</checkout_cart_product_add_after>`

In the Observer file, add a method like this:

```
public function checkoutCartProductAddAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

    // some stuff to find out price and current seller ID

    $options = array(
        array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Custom Data'),
            'value' => array(
                'custom_price' => $customPrice,
                'item_seller_id' => $sellerId
            )
        )
    );

    $product = $item->getProduct();

    $product->addCustomOption('c_data', serialize($options));
    if ($product->getCustomOption('c_data')) {
        $item->addOption($product->getCustomOption('c_data'))
            ->save();
    } else {
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Could not set product options.'));
    }

    // some more stuff if you need to
}
```

This should make magento handle the items as different cart items.

Comment: Sorry i am not getting

Comment: What do you not get exactly?

Comment: I need to add new module for thais

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. No, you can use this method in your Observer.php